# Apache Solr "HTTP ERROR 503" after unloading Core and trying to re-create it

Tags: java, solr, jetty

I was looking how I can query some XML files with Solr and thus I went and changed the `schema.xml` file located under the `collection1` directory.

Then I launched a query, which I knew it should return 1 result but in vain.

So I figured I might have to re-load the CORE (the idea was taken from [CoreAdmin -Solr Wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin)). So I did, but for some reason I wasn't able to. Thats said, I decided to restart the service (`sorl/example` `java -jar start.jar`) and now I am getting this error:

```
HTTP ERROR 503

Problem accessing /solr/. Reason:

    Server is shutting down or failed to initialize

Powered by Jetty://
```

This is the command prompt output which shows that server is running??

```
0    [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server  û jetty-8.1.10.v20130312
75   [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider  û Depl
oyment monitor C:\Users\kapel_000\Desktop\solr-4.10.2\example\contexts at interv
al 0
83   [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager  û Deployable added
: C:\Users\kapel_000\Desktop\solr-4.10.2\example\contexts\solr-jetty-context.xml

1916 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor  û NO JSP
 Support for /solr, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
2066 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter  û SolrDispatchFilt
er.init()
2083 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  û JNDI not configured
 for solr (NoInitialContextEx)
2083 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  û solr home defaulted
 to 'solr/' (could not find system property or JNDI)
2084 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  û new SolrResourceLoa
der for directory: 'solr/'
2248 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSolr  û Loading container configura
tion from C:\Users\kapel_000\Desktop\solr-4.10.2\example\solr\solr.xml
2323 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CoresLocator  û Config-defined core root
directory: C:\Users\kapel_000\Desktop\solr-4.10.2\example\solr
2334 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer  û New CoreContainer 307272
05
2335 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer  û Loading cores into CoreC
ontainer [instanceDir=solr/]
2351 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory  û S
etting socketTimeout to: 0
2352 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory  û S
etting urlScheme to: null
2359 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory  û S
etting connTimeout to: 0
2360 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory  û S
etting maxConnectionsPerHost to: 20
2362 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory  û S
etting corePoolSize to: 0
2363 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory  û S
etting maximumPoolSize to: 2147483647
2363 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory  û S
etting maxThreadIdleTime to: 5
2364 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory  û S
etting sizeOfQueue to: -1
2365 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory  û S
etting fairnessPolicy to: false
2596 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.UpdateShardHandler  û Creating UpdateSh
ardHandler HTTP client with params: socketTimeout=0&connTimeout=0&retry=false
2599 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.logging.LogWatcher  û SLF4J impl is org.slf4j.
impl.Log4jLoggerFactory
2601 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.logging.LogWatcher  û Registering Log Listener
 [Log4j (org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory)]
2603 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer  û Host Name:
7194 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CoresLocator  û Looking for core definiti
ons underneath C:\Users\kapel_000\Desktop\solr-4.10.2\example\solr
7213 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CoresLocator  û Found core collection1 in
 C:\Users\kapel_000\Desktop\solr-4.10.2\example\solr\collection1\
7215 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CoresLocator  û Found core collection1 in
 C:\Users\kapel_000\Desktop\solr-4.10.2\example\solr\collection5\
7216 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CoresLocator  û Found 2 core definitions
7220 [main] ERROR org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter  û Could not start
Solr. Check solr/home property and the logs
7270 [main] ERROR org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  û null:org.apache.solr.common.S
olrException: Found multiple cores with the name [collection1], with instancedir
s [C:\Users\kapel_000\Desktop\solr-4.10.2\example\solr\collection1\] and [C:\Use
rs\kapel_000\Desktop\solr-4.10.2\example\solr\collection5\]
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.checkForDuplicateCoreNames(CoreCon
tainer.java:297)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:241)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.createCoreContainer(SolrDi
spatchFilter.java:189)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.ja
va:136)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:119)

        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLife
Cycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.ja
va:719)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletC
ontextHandler.java:265)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.jav
a:1252)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandle
r.java:710)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494
)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLife
Cycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(Stan
dardStarter.java:39)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:1
86)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentM
anager.java:494)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.j
ava:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(Scan
ningAppProvider.java:145)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(Sc
anningAppProvider.java:56)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:609)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:540)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:403)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:337)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLife
Cycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(Scanni
ngAppProvider.java:121)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLife
Cycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(Deploymen
tManager.java:555)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.
java:230)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLife
Cycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(Aggregate
LifeCycle.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHand
ler.java:58)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrappe
r.java:96)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:280)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLife
Cycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:12
59)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:118
2)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:473)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:615)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:96)

7276 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter  û SolrDispatchFilt
er.init() done
7302 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector  û Started SocketCo
nnector@0.0.0.0:8983
```

Does any of this make any sense? Did I messed up badly (more than once?) or is it something simle I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your error:

> 7270 [main] ERROR org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  û
>   null:org.apache.solr.common.S olrException: Found multiple cores with
>   the name [collection1], with instancedirs
>   [C:\Users\kapel_000\Desktop\solr-4.10.2\example\solr\collection1] and
>   [C:\Users\kapel_000\Desktop\solr-4.10.2\example\solr\collection5]

Check your config, you've got the core collection1 configured twice. Once pointing to `example\solr\collection1` and once to `example\solr\collection5`

Answer (score -1):

HTTP ERROR 503
Problem accessing /solr/. Reason:

```
Server is shutting down or failed to initialize
```